# Good way to speed up full screen flash video on laptop

Tags: windows-7, video, performance, flash

I like hulu.com and watch shows a lot.  I have a laptop that came with Windows Vista.  Watching full screen made the video choppy (skip frames).  So I reinstalled with XP.  This fixed the choppiness.  I have since upgraded to 7 RC 64 bit.  The choppiness is back.  Is there any optimization for Windows 7 that might help alleviate the choppiness?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/67239/full-screen-flash-lags-on-windows-7 for some ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are, the choppiness is due to slow hardware (or a strain on system resources). Full screen flash can be pretty resource intensive. GPU accelerated Flash would fix this, but i don't think that is available yet.

Comment: Flash 9c introduced hardware acceleration but it doesn't seem to do anything with most Flash apps. Apparently the developer has to do work to enable any resource savings that way (speculation, I don't know Flash). Youtube videos seem to work by now, though. But I remember that in the early days when Flash got that ability the setting didn't change anything.

Comment: Flash Player 10.2 has even more GPU support.  Not sure if Hulu have implemented it yet or not.