# Full screen flash lags on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, video, flash, fullscreen

I have been experiencing an issue since I've up upgraded to Windows 7 where all flash videos have horrible frame rates when run in full screen mode.  I have tried multiple browsers and i have the latest version of flash and video drivers. I have tried re-installing flash and disabling hardware acceleration.  The problem occurs on youtube and hulu.

This is a clean install on a Core 2 duo with 4GB RAM and an Nvidia 8400M GS.

Comment: Are you using the debug version of the Flash player? Just something to check.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I think I've got this figured out.  I thought it might have had something to do with Aero being on because it started working fine when I disabled it.  However, I have been able to reproduce it by messing with the hardware acceleration feature.

I think the fix is indeed to disable hardware acceleration.  I didn't see any change at first, but when I reloaded the page (F5, or CTRL+F5 for full reload) it started working.

The fix:

1. Take the flash video out of full screen.
2. Right click on the video and select 'Settings'
3. In the 'Display' tab, un-check the 'Enable hardware acceleration' check-box.
4. Refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to nvidia site and download the drivers compatible with windows 7 , don't just update them. My computer used to have the same trouble when i used full screen and then it restarted. The new drivers fixed the problem. Hope i helped a little